# Anyways to reclaim a Visual Studio Professional 2019 lisence key from an old computer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I had Visual Studio Professional 2019 on my old computer. Unfortunately, the old computer is bricked and I can not turn my old computer on.

Are there anyways to reclaim my Visual Studio Professional 2019's key from my old computer ?

Comment: Can you not login to your Visual Studio account online? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/subscriptions/

Answer (score 1):

If you have ever logged-in to your Visual Studio subscription on
the Web, you may find your key in
https://my.visualstudio.com/productkeys.
If you have not, you need to try to logon to the website with the
credentials that you have, if you have saved them somewhere.

Otherwise, I suggest to try to put the system disk of the
old computer in another computer to boot from it.
Windows will not be activated on that computer, but will
still work well-enough for your purpose.

For more information, see Microsoft's article
[Finding and claiming product keys in Visual Studio subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/find-keys).